# The (statistically unsound) exploratory study (no particular hypothesis)

Tags: hypothesis-testing, exploratory-data-analysis

It seems like a proposed study gets penalised if it doesn't also predict the direction of an effect. For instance, if I want to see the effect of a certain medication on happiness ratings, but do not predict whether I think they'll be decreasd or increased by that manipulation. Why is it considered unsound to run an exploratory study, i.e. one that doesn’t have a specific prediction (hypothesis) but simply wants to see what effect a certain manipulation has on another dependent variable (i.e. you have a hunch there's an effect there but don’t quite know in which direction it'll be)?

In other words, what exactly is the formal statistical principle that is violated if you run a study without formulating an apriori hypothesis? It seems that if you're happy to pay the 'penalties', e.g. use 2-tailed instead of 1-tailed tests and correct for all the multitude of tests, any exploratory result should be just as believable as those of a hypothesis-driven study!

Comment: Use of a 2-tailed test when the direction of an effect isn't pre-specified is "penalization" enough. What "multitude of tests" are you thinking about?

Comment: Sorry, I was unclear, I was referring to another possible exploratory study whereby you're just looking for correlations between various variables any pair of which you'd expect could be correlated

Comment: And about the penlization, it seemed to me that even if you are happy to pay that 'price' of e.g. a lower alpha value, a study that doesn't specify what direction it expects the effect to be in is still frowned upon - despite the fact that practically everyone uses 2-tailed and not 1-tailed tests.

Comment: I hope the question makes more sense now...

Comment: Yes (you should perhaps edit the question rather than adding clarification or extra detail in comments). I haven't answered simply because I haven't come across such attitudes (perhaps you could provide some references). What is widely denigrated (whether or not it's considered worthwhile in a particular case to correct p-values or widen confidence intervals to account for multiple comparisons), is deciding the form of the analysis based on the results of the experiment - transforming the response, re-grouping categorical predictors, choosing a test statistic, &c.; generally tweaking ...

Comment: ... things to give the "best" results - & then keeping mum about all of that; disregarding these "[researcher degrees of freedom](http://pss.sagepub.com/content/22/11/1359)" in the final analysis. For alleged examples see [Bem (2011), "Feeling the Future", *JPSS*, **100**, 3](http://www.drjudithorloff.com/Free-Articles/Feeling-Future.pdf) & [Witztum et al. (1994), "Equidistant Letter Sequences in the Book of Genesis", *Stat. Sci.*, **9**, 3](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.ss/1177010393). Every analysis involves some unknowns, otherwise there'd be no point to it, but you should try to make ...

Comment: ... the formal analysis broad enough to be able to treat them formally.